# Google play console. Регистрация россиянина проживающего не в России

Tags: google-play-console

Регестрирую аккаунт разработчика.
Страну указал: Грузия (проживаю сейчас)
Оплатил: $25 Crebo bank.
Отправил загранпаспорт на подтверждение личности. - Получил отказ.
Отправил российский паспорт на подтверждение личности. - Поулчил отказ.

Текст отказа:

> Нам не удалось подтвердить вашу личность. Вот с чем это связано:
> Официальное удостоверение личности с фотографией. Страна выдачи этого
> документа не совпадает с той, которую вы указали в платежном профиле.
> Отправьте нам изображение удостоверения личности, которое выпущено в
> стране, заданной в платежном профиле.

Платежный профиль я не заполнял. (Если карта оплаты комисси им не считается)

### Что я делаю не так в данной ситуции ?

Естественно, далее, я хочу оформить платежный профиль с реквизитами этой-же карты (Credo bank) по понятным причинам. Изменить страну в своем паспорте я не могу :)

Кто сталкивался с подобным ? Опишите пожалуйста куда копать ? Или кто то имел дело с регистрацией акка разраба из Грузии - опишите шаги пожалуйста.

Comment: ВНЖ есть? Я когда в Германии жил, аккаунты через карточку ВНЖ местную оформлял, вместо паспорта.

Comment: @DiMithras ВНЖ нет и пока не предвидится :( (знакомые советовали)

Comment: Тогда пытаться там как-то через коммунальные платёжки доказывать.

Comment: @DiMithras Проживаю в гостевом доме. Даже адреса не имею. Есть только улица.

Comment: С точки зрения здравого смысла, вы — турист. Соответственно, ваша страна — не страна, в которой вы находитесь на правах туриста. Туристам, как правило, запрещено получать доход в стране нахождения. Оформляйте ВНЖ, пытайтесь прикладывать к заявкам счета за коммуналку, оформленные на ваше имя.

Comment: @user_587 Да, вы правы. Но должен быть более вменяемый способ. Можно сдать на права в Грузии - но это разве не перебор для регистрации аккаунта ?

Comment: А как решил вопрос с монетизацией приложения?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Решено !

Создаем аккаунт разработчика и платежный профиль страны указанной в паспорте. Адрес указываем как в паспорте. Я же указывал страну проживания и соответствующий адрес. В созданный платежный профиль страны проживания можно добавить дебетовую карту ряда стран для оплаты комиссии.
Моя ошибка была в боязни что регистрация чего-то где есть упоминание слова "российский" не даст дальнейших действий.

Итого:
Гугл возвратил первый платеж по некоректному профилю и прислал письмо с подробными шагами. Я создал новый аккаунт разработчика (российский), платежный профиль (российский), в платежный профиль добавил карту (грузинскую), оплатил комиссию $25,отослал свой паспорт на проверку, и на следующий день получил подтверждение личности ! Квест пройден !

> Once you successfully select the correct payments profile, you can pay
> for the registration fee using any credit/debit card issued in any
> country. Note that the verification depends on the payments profile
> associated with your Play Console account. Since you do not currently
> have a visa or residence permit for Georgia, changing the country
> associated with your payments profile will allow you to be verified as
> a Russian citizen. In addition, your Play Console account has been
> closed. You can expect to see a refund of $25 to your financial
> institution within the next 7-10 business days. You'll also get an
> email from Google Payments with more details about your refund.

Comment: Здравствуйте, интересно а как получилось ввести БИК?, он же только в РФ есть, а в российских платежных профилях это поле по умолчанию должно быть заполнено

Answer (score 2):

У меня получилось, с первого раза (февраль 2024)!

0. Ищем знакомых с зарубежной картой, если сами не можем её оформить.
1. Переходим к созданию аккаунта, вводя все данные как нас попросят. Дополнительно ничего читать не надо - при создании всё указано максимально исчерпывающе.
2. Во время создания платёжного профиля указываем данные как в паспорте. Да, вы указываете ФИО русскими буквами, русский номер телефона, страну Россия и так далее.
3. На предпоследнем этапе потребуется ввести данные карты. Неважно, какой страны карта - продолжайте указывать свой российский адрес, как в паспорте. У меня он был автозаполнен на основании данных из платёжного профиля. Моя карта была оформлена не на меня, поэтому я указал что-то вроде "INSTANT CARD" (это будет работать даже если оригинал карты с настоящим именем). В моём случае карта Казахстана с тенге на счету.
4. Последний этап заключается в отправке двух разворотов российского паспорта - с именем и пропиской. Фотографии были сделаны на телефон, скидывал несжатые оригиналы. Настолько оригиналы, что случайно забыл повернуть прописку на 90 градусов, залил кривое фото .
5. Аккаунт будет подтверждён. В моём случае это заняло меньше 20 часов.

В общем, всё просто и максимально адекватно. Но если хотите чуть больше инфы, то вот она:

1. Сначала я прошёл регистрацию до оплаты, сохраняя вводимые данные (так как после закрытия страницы они удалятся).
2. После скинул данные своего аккаунта (предварительно установив временный пароль и двухфакторку) знакомому, так как он не хотел делиться своей картой.
3. Мы созвонились и с демонстрацией экрана вместе ввели все ранее сохранённые данные, заняло не более 5 минут, после он произвёл оплату.
4. Попрощавшись, я удалил его сессию через безопасность аккаунта.
5. На следующий день дождался подтверждения данных.
6. Сейчас пишу этот ответ.
7. После пойду обратно ставить основной пароль и удалять его карту из платёжного профиля (видел отзыв, что до подтверждения её лучше не удалять из аккаунта, не знаю насколько это правда, но он был не против немного подстраховаться).

Также стоит следовать [официальным рекомендациям](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/13628312):

- Следите за тем, чтобы контактная информация была актуальной. Google будет использовать эти данные, чтобы сообщать вам важные сведения об аккаунте разработчика Google Play. Время от времени мы можем писать или звонить вам, чтобы убедиться, что аккаунт активен. Кроме того, убедитесь, что ваши контактные данные разработчика верны, чтобы пользователи могли связаться с вами.
- Старайтесь не указывать в качестве общедоступной контактной информации адрес электронной почты, который вы использовали при создании аккаунта разработчика Google Play. Это особенно важно, если аккаунтом пользуются несколько разработчиков или компания. В этом случае можно настроить общий почтовый ящик, чтобы важные сообщения об аккаунте получали определенные специалисты в вашей команде или организации.
- Для корпоративного аккаунта обязательно указывайте электронную почту, напрямую связанную с вашей организацией, а не общеиспользуемый или личный адрес.

Answer (score 0):

Это делается для борьбы со спамерами приложений. Вы не можете иметь платежный профиль Грузии не являясь резидентом данной страны. Доказывается одним из следующих документов: паспорт, ВНЖ, водительское удостоверение Грузии. Поэтому, либо получаете ВНЖ, либо меняете платежный профиль на российский. Других вариантов нет.

Comment: Я не указывал свой платежный профиль, я всего лишь оплатил комиссию $25 с карты грузинского банка. В платежный профиль я заходил и он пустой. Требуется ввести различную информацию: BIC, банк-корреспондент и прочее.  Так-же я читал что даже из Росии все это возможно сделать но не совсем законными путями - от чего я сразу отказался. Получается это можно но нельзя. Так-же я не вижу смысла указывать платежный профиль российским, он ведь будет бесполезен в текущее время.

Comment: А что, можно водительское удостоверение получить и стать резидентом?) Резидентство, AFAIK, определяется именно через ВНЖ, длительность нахождения, либо местный контракт.

Comment: @DiMithras Нет, статус резидента оно не дает :). Но при регистрации нужно отослать скан одного из 4-х документов на выбор, в котором есть водительское удостоверение в котором будет указана страна соответствующая стране платежного профиля. Ведь проблема только в не соответствии стран.

Comment: @vito-Z80 верно да. Похоже дыра в  ̶з̶а̶к̶о̶н̶а̶х̶ правилах, потому что на права можно и как турист сдать )

Comment: @DiMithras А что подразумевается под длительностью нахождения ? Как это может помочь ? Я не особо понимаю, но если вы имеете ввиду что я смогу отправить сканы квитанций за ЖКХ и что то в этом духе, то думаю этот фокус не пройдет. Только если я не приклею свое фото на подобную квтанцию :)

Comment: @vito-Z80 по законодательству РФ налоговое президентство определяется по сроку пребывания (полгода), не важно гражданин или нет. Во многих странах что-то похожее, да и по тур. визе долго не поживёшь.

Comment: @DiMithras Да, об этом мне известно и для Грузии это пол года. Значит ли это что по сроку прибывания я могу получить налоговый документ Грузии ? Но опять-же я сомневаюсь что он подойдет под требуемые гуглом документы. В платежном профиле он не применно понадобится, но для завершения регистраци.. я не уверен.

Comment: @vito-Z80 я в Грузию не мигрировал никогда. Но по идее можно попробовать!

Comment: @vito-Z80 "Я не указывал свой платежный профиль" - Он автоматически создается по вашей карте. Его можно удалить, и создать новый профиль. "Так-же я не вижу смысла указывать платежный профиль российским, он ведь будет бесполезен в текущее время." - люди получают на Райфайзен оплату и еще несколько банков в России. Но это как лотерея, в любой день может прикрыться.

Answer (score 0):

Мне с 2020 года подтверждали личность(не было кнопки для отправки документа, после двух раз отказа). Тут я не знаю, что у них за фетиш,но Россиян из России кто не подтвердил личность, но есть аккаунт подтверждают по паспорту РФ. Сам совсем недавно добился подтверждения через поддержку, когда они решили мой аккаунт удалить из-за не активности. Теперь я подверженный, но через месяц могут акк удалить)) Хотя приложение я туда им пихаю, для активности.Посмотрим что будет 8 апреля 2024 года)