# Получить api ключ для карт Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps-api

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли сейчас в 2024 году получить ключ для использования api карт google maps?
В интернете ничего не сказано, статьи читал, нужна банковская карта, но пройдут ли платежи или ее регистрация из-за введенных санкций? Есть ли такие в России, кто получал ключ разработчика api у Google после введенных санкций?

Comment: Странно, неужели за два года никто не пытался получить ключ у гугла с привязкой банковской карты..

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1528155/264178 это не апи карт, но может можно почерпать "идеи"